# Как оборвать long-polling req с помощью middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

При подключении к серверу приложение кидает long-polling запрос, если он обрывается, значит файлы пользователя поменялись.

Этот запрос должен обрываться при вызове специального middleware, который будет прикреплен к роутам, меняющим файлы юзера.

Это нужно, чтобы при изменении файлов на одном пк, содержимое на других обновилось (без вебсокетов)

Я пришел к тому, что каждый long-polling req добавляет юзернейм в спец массив, middleware его оттуда удаляет

Но!
Как сделать, чтобы при изменении этого массива, внутри long-polling req происходила проверка на то, надо ли его оборвать или нет (желательно без бесконечных while, т к боюсь по производительности ударит)

Предложите какие то решения моей проблемы